# HTML/CSS How to make such a button?

Tags: html, css, button

I want to style a button and make it look like this:

[image: button preview]

I tried the code below, but it looks totally different.

```
button {
   width: 500px;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

I am interested in the border radius.

Comment: try to adjust the border-radius, let's say from 50% to 8px

Comment: According to what he wants, I suggest to set 15px because it will be 50% of the fixed height which is 30px

Comment: Set border-radius as 15px for example. It should be help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use something like this:

```css
button {
   width: 500px;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 15px; /* here we just change the radius to a fixed one, according to fixed height */
   border: none; /* here we remove black border */
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

For text, you can use [text formating](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You have border-radius wrong. With your border-radius : 50%, will try to make the button oval kind of shape. So use px units to make rounded corners. Also there is default border on the button, so you have to set border to none. Below css would do the same thing :

```css
button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set border-radius to px instead of %. Half of the height (30px) will make it nice and round. Anything less will make it less rounded.

```
button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
button {
   width: 500px;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   border: none;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<button>text here</button>
```